# mysql result for second table same row length with the first table

Tags: php, database, pdo

I'm facing a trouble whereby my treatment record consist of 6 rows of data and my upcoming appointment row only consist of 1 row of data but now my upcoming appointment row also duplicated into 6 rows as my first table.

here is mysql code:

```
if(empty($_GET['name'])) {
   echo 'Please don\'t try to hack!<br /><a href="./" title="Retry">Click here to <b>retry</b> again</a>';
   exit;
}

require_once 'dbconnect.php';
$p_id = $_GET['name'];

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM appointment a
            LEFT JOIN customer c
            ON a.customer_id = c.cust_id
            AND a.deleted = '0'
            LEFT JOIN services s
            ON c.cust_id = s.customer_id
            AND s.deleted = '0'
            WHERE c.slug  LIKE :id";

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array('id' => $p_id));
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $cs = $q->fetchAll();

} catch (PDOException $pe) {
    die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
```

and here is my html view code:

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Customer Record</h1>
    Name: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($cs[0]['fname'].' '.$cs[0]['lname']); ?> <br />
    Gender: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($cs[0]['gender']); ?> <br />
    Mobile Number: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($cs[0]['number']); ?> <br /><br />
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Treatment</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($cs as $r):?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php if($r['treatment'] === NULL) { echo "No Record Found"; } else { echo htmlspecialchars($r['treatment']); } ?></td>
                <td><?php if($r['date'] === NULL) { echo "No Record Found"; } else { echo htmlspecialchars($r['date']); } ?></td>
                <td><?php if($r['service_id'] === NULL) { echo "No Record Found"; } else { ?><a href="editrecord.php?name=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['slug']) ?>&id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['service_id']) ?>">Edit Record</a> or <a href="deleterecord.php?name=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['slug']) ?>&id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['service_id']) ?>">Delete Record</a><?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Upcoming Appointment</th>
                <th>Appointment Type</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($cs as $r):?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php if($r['appt_date'] === NULL) { echo "No Record Found"; } else { echo htmlspecialchars($r['appt_date']); } ?></td>
                <td><?php if($r['appointment_type'] === NULL) { echo "No Record Found"; } else { echo htmlspecialchars($r['appointment_type']); } ?></td>
                <td><?php if($r['service_id'] === NULL) { echo "No Record Found"; } else { ?><a href="editrecord.php?name=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['slug']) ?>&id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['service_id']) ?>">Edit Record</a> or <a href="deleterecord.php?name=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['slug']) ?>&id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['service_id']) ?>">Delete Record</a><?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
        <a href="./">Seach Again</a><br /><br />
        <a href="addrecord.php?name=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['slug']) ?>">Add Record</a>

</div>
```

I not sure where did I get wrong, but I suspect my sql code part get wrong.

Here is [SQLFiddle for LEFT JOIN Appointment Table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ef7f4/4)

And Here is [SQLFiddle for LEFT JOIN Appointment Table and LEFT JOIN Services Table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ef7f4/3)

I need this three table data to show all the information, if I use only left join from Appointment Table it shows no error of duplication on 6 row, but if I use left join appointment table and left join service table, my Treatment table result show 6 row which is correct but my Upcoming Table also 6 rows of same result whereas it only have 1 row of data in database.

Please advise where did I go wrong.

Comment: Please post the desired outcome for each Fiddle.

Comment: @PM77-1: actually I want one outcome only, both Fiddle just show sql query method. If you refer to [SQLFiddle for LEFT JOIN Appointment Table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ef7f4/4) it show `1 result` if you refer to [SQLFiddle for LEFT JOIN Appointment Table and LEFT JOIN Services Table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ef7f4/3) it show `6 results` what I want in my html view `<tr><th>Treatment</th><th>Date</th><th>Action</th></tr>` show the six results and `<tr>
<th>Upcoming Appointment</th><th>Appointment Type</th><th>Action</th></tr>` show only 1 result and not 6 results by using second Fiddle method

Comment: @PM77-1 do you able to assist me in this question?

Comment: I'm not a PHP programmer. If you want my help with your **SQL** part, I would like to see the desired result of your queries added to your post (just plain data).